# How to find edges with common nodes in Graph Networkx?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have this graph:

```
G = nx.MultiGraph()

source_nodes = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'D']
target_nodes = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

for u,v in zip(source_nodes, target_nodes):
    G.add_edge(u, v)
```

and the edges I get are:

```
(A, B)
(A, C)
(B, D)
(D, E)
```

if the target node of an edge is the source node from another edge, I would like to create an edge between them. For instance, for the above example the new edges will be:

`(A, D)` and `(A, E)`.

I'm new in Networkx and I'm not sure how to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firstly, you use [MultiGraph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multigraph.html). It is not directed and doesn't store info about sources and targets (they become equal connected nodes). You should use [DiGraphs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html#) or [MultiDiGraphs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multidigraph.html) to store info in a directed graph.
2. NetworkX DiGraphs and MultiDiGraphs [has functions](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/digraph.html#reporting-nodes-edges-and-neighbors) `predecessors` and `successors`, that can be applied to a particular node. You can use them to check if an edge from predecessor to successor exists, and if not, create it.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()  # Not a MultiGraph! (can be MultiDiGraph)

source_nodes = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'D']
target_nodes = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

for u,v in zip(source_nodes, target_nodes):
    G.add_edge(u, v)

# For each node
for n in G.nodes:
    # We check all predecessors and successors
    for p in G.predecessors(n):
        for s in G.successors(n):
            # If graph has no edge from predecessor to successor
            if (p, s) not in G.edges:
                print(p, s)  # Print, can be removed
                # We add this node
                G.add_edge(p, s)
```

If you want to create edges not for all nodes, but for a set of nodes, you can replace `G.nodes:` in the line `for n in G.nodes:` with a given set of nodes, like:

`for n in [1, 2, 3]:`

If you want to create edges only for one node, you don't need the main loop:

```
NODE_ID = 2

# We check all predecessors and successors of a node
for p in G.predecessors(NODE_ID):
    for s in G.successors(NODE_ID):
        # If graph has no edge from predecessor to successor
        if (p, s) not in G.edges:
            print(p, s)  # Print, can be removed
            # We add this node
            G.add_edge(p, s)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine but creates edges for all the elements, I can't use it for very specific elements as in my description...